# Лёгкое портирование desktop приложения в web-приложение

Tags: c#

Извиняюсь за возможно профанский вопрос, но я и есть профан что в C# что в web.

Есть ли способ портировать приложение desktop написанное на C# в web приложение на том же C# без лишних телодвижений?

Чтобы не писать все заново, а просто что-то добавить, что-то убавить?

Answer (score 0):

Таких способов нет. Можно частично использовать ваше приложение ( его бизнес-логику) для написания Web-сайта на `ASP.NET Web Forms` либо `ASP.NET MVC`.

Comment: Ну почему же, если автор использует одну из стандартных библиотек форм - то теоретически форму можно рендерить в html вместо экрана, onclick превращается в postback - значит вероятно можно. Вот движения мыши обработать - врядли, т.к. с# конвертнуть в js не выйдет. А если чисто "бизнес форма" - думаю выйдет.

Answer (score 0):

Есть подход к построению приложений (безотносительно языка программирования - можно применить хоть к C# хоть к Java), который называется Domain Driven Design, DDD. В русской литературе - проблемно-ориентированное программирование.

Согласно этому подходу вы строите приложение определённым образом по слоям, концентрируя в одном слое бизнес-логику, в другом - работу с базой данных и т.п.

Данный подход позволяет не писать заново всё приложение, когда вам приходится вместо консольного приложения добавить скажем мобильное приложение или веб-приложение, а переиспользовать по-максимуму свой код.

Выглядит это примерно следующим образом: у вас есть solution (решение) Visual Studio с набором проектов (обычно около пяти, это варьируется), один из проектов допустим веб-приложение. Если вы разрабатывали по гайдлайнам DDD свой проект, то для создания мобильного приложения вам достаточно добавить новый проект для мобильного решения и использовать код из других проектов.

Не для каждого приложения это возможно. Если у вас приложение делает скриншоты экрана, то переносить его под мобильные устройства - это писать много дополнительной логики, а переносить под веб вообще нет смысла.

Однако например если писать какие-либо CRUD приложения, ориентированные на бизнес (системы учёта заказов и товаров), то их будет намного легче перенести, если воспользоваться подходом DDD.

Поэтому учитывать специфику приложения конечно надо.

Однако, сразу хочу предупредить, что данный подход является одним из самым сложных в освоении подходов к написанию программного обеспечения и из-за своей сложности и цены применяется относительно редко.

Поэтому стоит ли изучать такой подход на вашем уровне знания платформы .Net - вопрос открытый.

Comment: Что то вы все перемешали. Какое отношение DDD имеет к отделению логики от представления? Почему не MVC/MVP/MVVM/MVW/etc.. ? DDD - это не про разделение UI от логики и не про разделение солюшена по проектам, это имхо совсем из другой оперы.